# Is there a tool to do packet mirroring in CentOS 5.9?

Tags: iptables, centos5, packet-capture

I know `iptables` + `xtables` can do it in more recent versions using the TEE target supplied by the xtables-addon package for iptables. However, the kernel in CentOS 5.9 is 2.6.18 and this version is not sufficient for any version of xtables-addons (2.6.19 is sufficient, however, I can't upgrade the kernel/OS on this box of mine).

So, is there some other tool that can do it? I need to mirror UDP packets to a different host on the same network.